# ShortCut URL Redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, shortcut

To get straight to the point.

I have this URL: http://example.com/?open=encyclopedia&letter=s&term=storm and I want this shortcut URL - http://example.com/storm - to redirect to the first URL: http://example.com/?open=encyclopedia&letter=s&term=storm

I have around 1.000 encyclopedic terms and I want this redirection to work for each term entered. For Example: if a visitor enters http://example.com/Storm to automatically be redirected to the page here: http://example.com/?open=encyclopedia&letter=s&term=storm OR http://example.com/Dried_Plant to http://example.com/?open=encyclopedia&letter=d&term=dried+plant

I prefer some htaccess solution to this, if possible.
If not, give what you can give.
I have no example code for this, since I do not know where to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Croises** answer is good if your link looks like following

> mysite.com/?open=encyclopedia&letter=s&term=/storm

`REQUEST_URI` is adding a trailing slash. Your link don't have one:

> mysite.com/?open=encyclopedia&letter=s&term=storm

I think this is what you are looking for

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(.+)$

RewriteRule ^(.) ?open=encyclopedia&letter=$1&letter=%1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you redirect it all to your page `encyclopedia`. And then consider with php what you can do with it (like finding the first letter or change with _ or others)

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ encyclopedia?term=%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L]
```

With correct first letter (`letter=`), change the last line with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.) encyclopedia?letter=$1&term=%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L]
```

Comment: How is with mysite.com/?open=encyclopedia&letter=s&term=storm ?

Comment: Change your link to `http://example.com/storm` in the page. htaccess can't do that for you.

Comment: Marvellously well! Deepest Thank You.